# How do I inject a variable into a string within the template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my page I have a:

```
<ul>
    <li
        class="validation-labels"
        v-for="(label, key) of labels" v-bind:key="key">
        {{ constants.validationRequirements[label.type] }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

`label` looks like: `{ type: string, value: any }`

`constants.validationRequirements` looks like:

```
validationRequirements: {
    'capitals': 'Must include {{ value }} capitals',
    'minLength': 'Must be a minimum length of {{ value }}'
}
```

What's the best way to inject `label.value` in as `value` from the constant string?

Comment: The Vue template doesn't insert anything into the `{{ value }}` inside the constant - because it's just a string

Comment: you probably can't do it as is, you should probably turn it into a function so something like `'capitals': function (value) { return \`Must include ${value} capitals\` }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li
        class="validation-labels"
        v-for="(label, key) of labels" v-bind:key="key">
        {{ validationReqs(label.type, label.value) }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your computed property:

```
validationReqs(type, value) {
  return this.constants.validationRequirements[type]
         .replace('{{ value }}', value);
}
```